# Project Euler #1 in Ruby with duration

Tags: performance, ruby, programming-challenge

I have done #1 of Project Euler's in Ruby. Using two different approaches. One uses set, another uses reduce.

```
require 'set'

start = Time.now

s1 = Set.new (1..1000/3.floor).map { |x| 3 * x }
s2 = Set.new (1..1000/5.floor).map { |x| 5 * x }
sum = s1.merge(s2).to_a.inject(:+)

duration = Time.now - start 

puts "Sum: #{sum}, time elapsed #{duration} s"
```

Second method

```
start = Time.now
sum = (1..1000).select{ |x| x % 3 == 0 || x % 5 == 0 }.reduce(:+)
duration = Time.now - start
```

The second method consistently performs better than first method:

method 1: time elapsed 0.000364 s

method 2: time elapsed 0.000198 s

I wonder if it is a correct way to time how long the process takes. And whether it is considered to be performant. Also curious how other languages performs compares to this two algo. Any advice are welcomed~

Comment: Just an observation (and a personal preference), I favor `.zero?`, so `x % 3 == 0` becomes `(x % 3).zero?`, and same with the second check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performing benchmarks with such small values is pretty much meaningless, you will usually be concerned with larger values. And this is how you  tipically compare the time performance of different snippets:

```
require 'benchmark'
require 'set'

n = 1_000_000
Benchmark.bm do |b|
  b.report("sets") do
    s1 = Set.new (1..n/3.floor).map { |x| 3 * x }
    s2 = Set.new (1..n/5.floor).map { |x| 5 * x }
    sum = s1.merge(s2).inject(0, :+)
  end

  b.report("select") do
    sum = (1..n).select { |x| x % 3 == 0 || x % 5 == 0 }.reduce(0, :+)
  end
end
```

Output:

```
         user     system      total        real
sets    0.550000   0.020000   0.570000 (  0.580492)
select  0.200000   0.000000   0.200000 (  0.207238)
```

Answer (score 1):

Code duplication:

```
s1 = Set.new (1..n/3.floor).map { |x| 3 * x }
s2 = Set.new (1..n/5.floor).map { |x| 5 * x }
```

The 2 lines above are  pretty similar aren't them? What if you want to add 100 more divisors? Will you write 100 more lines? I suggest using some functions:

```
def divisible_by_up_to(divisor, limit)
    Set.new (1..limit/divisor.floor).map { |x| divisor * x}
end

def divisible_by_all_up_to(divisors_list, limit)
    # This is pseudo-code
    set.merge_all([divisible_by_up_to(limit, divisor)
                       for divisors in divisors_list])
end
```

Your code than becomes more easily exapandable, modular and readable

```
sum = divisible_by_all_up_to([3,5], 1000).to_a.inject(:+)
```